# Error connecting to SQL database I have created with a user I have created

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some problems with connecting to a databases using the users i have created.Firstly i created the users like this:

```
create user util1 identified by user1;

create user util2 identified by user2;

create user util3 identified by user3;

create user util4 identified by user4;

create user util5 identified by user5;

create user util6 identified by user6;

create user util7 identified by user7;

create user util8 identified by user8;

grant dba to util1,util2,util3,util4,util5,util6,util7,util8;

select lpad(' ', 2*level) || granted_role "User, his roles and privileges"
   from (select null grantee, username granted_role from dba_users where username like upper('%UTIL%')
         union
            select grantee, granted_role from dba_role_privs
         union
            select grantee, privilege from dba_sys_privs)
                                           start with grantee is null
                                           connect by grantee = prior granted_role;
```

This is working fine.But when i try to create a table using "util1"'s rights it doesn't work:

```
connect util1/user1 AS SYSDBA;
create table pr1(
             cod_subansamblu number(4),
             denumire varchar2(20) not null,
             cantitate number(7,3),
             UM varchar2(3),
             pret_unitar number(9,2),
             cod_ansamblu number(4),
             cod_sectie number(4)  not null,
             constraint pr1_cod_subansamblu_pk primary key(cod_subansamblu),
             constraint pr1_UM_chk check(UM in ('BUC','ML','MP','MC','SET'))
             );
```

I really don't know what is going wrong. Help will be greatly appreciated.

The error message I receive is:

```
Last Execution Details

Results        


Statistics        Plan                

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Comment: Why do you connect "`as sysdba`". That should only be used for maintenance work. Also granting DBA to a "regular" user is not a very good idea. Just grant those users `connect` and `resource` if that is a development DB. If it's a production DB, you should grant those users `connect` and each `CREATE` privilege separately.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Oracle is deprecating RESOURCE (and CONNECT and DBA) in 11g.  " Oracle recommends that you design your own roles for database security rather than relying on this role. This role may not be created automatically by future releases of Oracle Database" http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authorization.htm

Comment: @APC: yes I know. That's why I said for a production DB that role should not be used. But for a development DB it is quite convenient.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I disagree: it takes virtually no time at all to knock up a script which grants the required privileges.  I mean, in almost all cases RESOURCE doesn't grant everything the developer needs (tablespace quota, additional system privileges, permissions on other schemas' objects).  So we need to write a bespoke script anyway.  Plus RESOURCE is a role, which creates problems if the developer has to write a stored procedure which uses  those privileges.

Comment: @APC: you have a good point regarding the role vs. stored procedure problem. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
SQL> create table pr1(
             cod_subansamblu number(4),
             denumire varchar2(20) not null,
             cantitate number(7,3),
             UM varchar2(3),
             pret_unitar number(9,2),
             cod_ansamblu number(4),
             cod_sectie number(4)  not null,
             constraint pr1_cod_subansamblu_pk primary key(cod_subansamblu),
             constraint pr1_UM_chk check(UM in ('BUC','ML','MP','MC','SET'))
             );  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11  

Table created.

SQL>
```

So it's hard to understand why it throws ORA-00900 when you run it.  What client are you using to run it?  SQL*Plus?  An IDE like TOAD?   Can you provide a cut'n'paste of the complete session so we can see *exactly* what's going on?

---

The other thing to bear in mind is, if you connect using `as sysdba` you login to the database as SYS, regardless of whether you specify a user in the CONNECT string:

```
SQL> conn apc/password as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> sho user
USER is "SYS"
SQL>
```

(This only works if you are logged into the OS as the `oracle` account or other appropriately privileged user).

So you may think you are running your create table statement as UTIL1 but you would in fact be running it as SYS, which is not a good idea.  In fact it is bad practice.